# How similar to a crewed flight will SpaceX Demo Mission 1 be?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2

With the upcoming premiere of the Dragon 2 in SpaceX's DM1 launch, I was wondering how similar it will be to a mission with actual astronauts. What I mean by this is things like:

- Will the launch abort system be armed and live?
- Will time be allocated for simulated astronauts to walk through the crew access arm?
- Will communications and checklists with simulated astronauts be completed?
- Are there going to be mannequin astronauts?

Comment: Great question! We may not know until it happens though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Maybe I'll edit my question to be in the past tense afterwards :)